# How can Discriminator and Generator loss both move to 0?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, gan

I have been working with GANs for years and I still can't figure this out. A common thing I see is when the loss of both G and D are near zero. I usually use MSE or cross entropy loss.

Shouldn't this be impossible regardless of whether your GAN setup is good/bad/stable/unstable?

The loss for G is defined by how well it fools D. The loss for D is defined by how well it is not fooled by G. So a zero loss for G means it is fooling D every time, but a zero loss for D means it is never being fooled. So in other words when both losses are 0 it means D is both never and always being fooled. They are defined as inverses of each other. How could this happen?

Here is a good link where they purposely create instability that causes G and D to both be near zero loss and it has code for reproducing. Relevant info is at the end.
[Link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/practical-guide-to-gan-failure-modes/)

Comment: since there are several popular loss functions for GANs, could you include which one you've been working with?

Comment: Mean square error and binary cross entropy both give this problem. I know W-GAN loss is a bit different and it might make sense for this to happen but I never use W distance loss